# Federal Perkins Loan is showing up unsubsidized despite not taking any unsubsidized loans

Tags: united-states, loans, student-loan, school

I've been repaying student debt and my university recently sent a loan that I didn't know I had to a collection agency. The loan is listed as a "federal Perkins direct Stafford" loan that is unsubsidized, but I don't remember ever taking an unsubsidized loan.

I've tried contacting my university and they said that they had no power in the situation because they gave the loan to a collection agency. The collection agency I contacted said that the loan was sent to them as unsubsidized so they had no power in the situation either.

I've searched on the internet and I've discovered that Perkins loans are subsidized but Stafford loans can be subsidized or unsubsidized. I'm not really sure who to contact or how to confirm if the loan is really subsidized or unsubsidized.

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I'm very confused and don't want to have to pay anything that I don't have to.

Note: It has been 2 years since I've been in school and the loan was awarded in 2015. My FAFSA was filled out by my parents.

Comment: How long has it been since you were in school?  Did they give you any clue as to when the loan was awarded/funded? Did you fill out the FAFSA or did your parents?

Comment: It has been 2 year since I've been in school and the loan was awarded in 2015. My FAFSA was filled out by my parents.

Comment: What does it matter if it's subsidized or unsubsidized? Shouldn't you simply be trying to figure out if this loan is really yours or not?

Answer (score 2):

Based om this comment:

> It has been 2 years since I've been in school and the loan was awarded
> in 2015. My FAFSA was filled out by my parents.

I would start with your parents. Somebody had to use those funds to pay the tuition. It would also seem that a reference to the loans would appear on your or your parents tax forms.  The financial aid forms from the university in the original time period should have specified the amount and the type of aid.